# Subscripting into an empty matrix is not supported matrix coder

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-coder

I have a matlab file, working fine,

I am trying to conver it using auto coder, however I get an error,

`??? Subscripting into an empty matrix is not supported.`

```
ct = 0;
while i <= 1800
        [xx, cc, vv] = doSomething(x, somevalue, Param1, dt);
        %things happening ...
        if something
           flowDt(ct+1) = vv;
           ct = ct + 1;
        end
end
```

I tried then to declare it before the loop because I got an error:
`??? Undefined function or variable 'flowDt'.'`

```
flowDt = [];
ct = 0;
while i <= 1800
        [xx, cc, vv] = doSomething(x, somevalue, Param1, dt);
        %things happening ...
        if something
           flowDt(ct+1) = vv;
           ct = ct + 1;
        end
end
```

now I am stuck not knowing what is causing this issue:
`??? Subscripting into an empty matrix is not supported.`

Comment: Have you tried `flowDt = 0` instead of `[]`?

Comment: that was kind of solve it, however, I did both [] then made it equal to 0, solved. you may post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variable as `0` rather than an empty matrix `[]`

```
flowDt = [];
```

then

```
flowDt = 0; was the solution
```

so `flowDt = 0` will initialize the array, making it `not empty`

Answer (score 1):

`flow` is a Matlab function. That could be the problem. Try changing that variable's name

Comment: oh sorry I shortened the naming,